# need to enable my wireless capability

Tags: windows-7

This is my laptop -

Fujitsu Lifebook P series

- Intel(R) Core (TM) Duo CPU
- L7100 @ 1.20 GGz
- Memory 2.oo GB
- Hard Disk 111 GB
  Running Windows 7

My laptop worked just fine before when I turned on  my cell phone with the wifi hotspot and put the password in my computer and all of sudden it won't connect anymore and keeps telling me i need to enable the wifi compatibility???? I also unchecked the

> allow the computer to turn off this device to save power

still won't work. I also tried the function keys Fn key plus all the F1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12 no luck.

I'm not sure if this matters but I think it may have happened after I wanted to see if the speed and ext. would be any different if I tethered my cell to the laptop but no change in that either.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that some Toshiba users find this fixes the issue:

System Reset:

- Remove AC power
- Remove battery
- Hold down power button for about 30 seconds
- Put battery back in and hook up power and Start.

Comment: thanks for your reply I will try and let you know. I also cant stream anything off this computer even from youtube? my older one could.